# Runtime function resolution in C?

Tags: c

Suppose this is a C code:

```
int (*p)();
scanf("%d",&a);
if(a){
    p = function1;
}else{
    p=function2;
}
int b=(*p)();
```

Here, the function resolution is dependent on the value of `a`, so can this be considered as run time function resolution? or will the compiler simply make the `function1` and `function2` inline?
Can we say for sure that All function calls are resolved at compiler time in C?

Comment: I guess you are into code that is both unreadable and difficult to maintain

Comment: `p = function1();` --> `p = function1;`

Comment: `p = function1;` Drop the parantheses (unless `function1` itself returns a function pointer). `Can we say for sure that All function calls are resolved at compiler time in C?`. Define what you mean by `calls are resolved at compile time`.

Comment: It is not the exact code. take it as an algorithm instead of a code.

Comment: Well post your ***exact*** code.

Comment: Your edit shows why we ask for the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried: you are shifting the code as we comment.

Comment: There is no exact code. It is more like a theoretical confusion instead of a real code.

Comment: The compiler is free to implement the code any way it likes, provided that the observable output is correct.

Comment: @EdHeal this is a fairly typical use of function pointers , assuming the real code has other things going on too

Comment: There's no real "function resolution" here.  It's a function pointer assignment and dereference.  It doesn't need to resolve anything when you give it an address and then tell it to execute that address.  If there is no exact code, and you have a question about what the compiler is going to do, try it out and look at the assembly.  I wouldn't imagine a function call to a non-const function pointer would be inlined in any case.  Compilers are smart, but that seems quite  abit over the top.

Comment: I tried it, and the program is working fine. I just wanted to compare it with the polymorphism property and see whether polymorphism can be achieved without `virtual`

Comment: You marked this C.  Do you mean C++ virtual?  Function lookup is done with a vtable in C++.  If you want to do more research on true C polymorphism and OO design, you may want to read up on gobject and how it works.

Comment: I mean C without OOPS. I'll take a look at gobject though

Comment: @M.M - IMHO it is best to avoid function pointers.

Comment: @EdHeal There are plenty of cases where a function pointer is the tidiest solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int (*function_pointer)(void); /* Define a pointer variable. */
scanf("%d", &user_input);
if (user_input != 0) {
  function_pointer = &function1; /* Set the value of that variable
                                    depending on some user input. */
} else {
  function_pointer = &function2;
}
int result = function_pointer(); /* Use the value by calling the
                                    function. */
```

> Here, the function resolution is dependent on the value [..]

No. There are two functions, `function1` and `function2`. Both are resolved just like other used functions (probably) during linking (more detail below). What this actually does is determining *the addresses* to which control flow needs to be transferred when the function is called.

Only which function * actually gets called* depends on the user input. Very much the same as in this code snippet:

```
scanf("%d", &user_input);
int result;
if (user_input != 0) {
  result = function1();
} else {
  result = function2();
}
```

And since the above snippet has the same observable behavior as your original code a compiler could actually implement it that way. And if `function1` and/or `function2` matches the metric of the optimizer for inlining, then, yes, both functions could be inlined.

> Can we say for sure that All function calls are resolved at compiler time in C?

No, because some references to functions (or variables) will be resolved during link time (other translation units, static libraries), some during load time (shared libraries) and some during run time (`dlopen`).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I don't think we can assume this code to be a weak form of polymorphism, can we?

Comment: No.  It's a function pointer, and it behaves exactly like a function pointer should, without polymorphism.  "polymorphism" depends on a degree of transparency, and using, assigning, and declaring a function pointer are not transparent.

Comment: I'd rather say it's the way (some of) dynamic polymorphism is implemented, but we have an interface here (a function taking no parameters and returning an `int`) with different possible behavior, so I guess you could stretch the definition and name it that way. But better just call it for what it is: a function pointer.